# How can I run a function while the process is running in C Builder?

Tags: c++builder

I would like to know how can I add a function to the main loop of my application in C++Builder, like a new thread running asynchronously.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not certain I understand the question.  Are you asking to edit source code in a running program and compile and execute it while debugging?

Comment: Nope, just add a call to my function in the main loop if possible. (or a new running thread)

Comment: You answered your own question - call the function in a separate thread. So what is the actual problem? If you need to run it kn the main thread, then look into sending custom window messages to your Form's window.